# android : imageButton background : implement on state_pressed to scale the image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have in my android xml layout :

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item_up" />
```

I need to implement in background Imagebutton property : When the user clicks on imageButton, it scales up the image. (setScaleX(1.5)...)

Theres a way please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps inset Drawable can help you-
I am using the following code-

```
     <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:drawable="@drawable/your_shape_drawable" android:insetBottom="10dip"
     android:insetLeft="10dip" android:insetRight="10dip" android:insetTop="10dip"
     android:visible="true" />
```

**Edit:Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <inset android:insetBottom="-10dp" android:insetLeft="-10dp" android:insetRight="-10dp" android:insetTop="-10dp">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </inset>
    </item>

    <item>
        <inset android:insetBottom="10dp" android:insetLeft="10dp" android:insetRight="10dp" android:insetTop="10dp">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </inset>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I need to implement scale inside <item android:state_pressed="true" > tag

Comment: I agree with you. it works but the image not look good over the smaller one.

Comment: Its up to you you can set a large size image for the press state.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Java and use a ScaleAnimation , for example :

```
   ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.5f, 1, 1.5f);

    scaleAnimation.setDuration(1000);  // animates for 1000 ms
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true); // stays 1.5f after animation

    yourImageView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

And start the animation in your ImageButton OnClickListener